# Merge two dataframes on value in column of df1 in comma separated values in column of df2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Input: two dataframes with the below data:
df1: (note EmployeeID is a string of comma separated values)

```
| Employee Name | EmployeeID |
|---------------|------------|
| John          | 2, 22      |
| Kim           | 3          |
```

df2:

```
| EmployeeID | Hours |
|------------|-------|
| 2          | 8     |
| 3          | 10    |
```

I want to merge df1 and df2 on df2.EmployeeID in list of ID's in df1.EmployeeID.

Output:

```
| Employee Name | EmployeeID | Hours |
|---------------|------------|-------|
| John          | 2,22       | 8     |
| Kim           | 3          | 10    |
```

Comment: If `EmployeeID` is `2,3,22` then `Hours` are `8,10` ?

Comment: No, it will be 8 + 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need match multiple values like `EmployeeID = 2,3,22` to `Hours=8+10` use mapping by dictionary in comprehension with `split`and `sum`:

```
#converted to strings for match splitted values
df2['EmployeeID'] = df2['EmployeeID'].astype(str)
d = df2.set_index('EmployeeID')['Hours'].to_dict()

f = lambda x: sum(d[y] for y in x.split(', ') if y in d)
df1['Hours'] = df1['EmployeeID'].apply(f)
print (df1)
  Employee Name EmployeeID Hours
0          John      2, 22     8
1           Kim          3    10
```

Another idea with matching by integers:

```
d = df2.set_index('EmployeeID')['Hours'].to_dict()

f = lambda x: sum(d[int(y)] for y in x.split(', ') if int(y) in d)
df1['Hours'] = df1['EmployeeID'].apply(f)
```